# .NET web service wrapper for multiple data sources

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest

I am asked to develop (from scratch) a REST web service in .NET that wrapps calls to various data sources:

- Databases (SQL, DB2, Oracle, etc)
- Other web services (SalesForce, Microsoft CRM, etc)
- Flat files
- etc

In the end, we would display this data in web UIs : grid, charts, etc. Other features include: caching, usage monitoring, user roles management. And the idea would be to query this web service with a syntax similar to Open Data.

The data sources configuration would be done in a database, or in a configuration file.
Ex: Data source "DS1" is of type "Database" to server "srv001" on database "db001" and gets data from stored procedure "sp001".

Before I start developing that from scratch, I first googled to see if an existing stardard component exists for that. But I couldn't find any.

=> Is there an existing tool on the market that does it out of the box (or close to out of the box) ?

Thank you

Alex

Comment: what do you expect from the tool you ask about?

Comment: Maybe you need an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), like [nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/) or [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)?

Comment: Hi,I am looking for something like this, but as a standard product : http://corememorydump.blogspot.ch/2012/02/wcf-data-services-reflection-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to expose data through a restful interface using .NET

- For exposing a data source as a service you should use [OData](http://www.odata.org/).
- For combining various sources, as you mentioned, as your own mashup service use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)
- If your service is only going to be used internally I would use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will be the most performant and easy-to-work-with option.